# Почему не получается добавить элемент с атрибутом в массив?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json

Есть плагин autocomplect который выдает совпадения по результатам поиска, и приписывает им атрибут data-context-key из ключом который соответствует элементу поиска.

Нужно чтоб все совпавшие элементы которым присвоен данный атрибут с ключом, добавились в массив. Ток вот проблема в том , что не хочет почему то добавлять.

Подскажите где косячу?

вот часть кода где добавляется атрибут с ключом:

```
 create: function() {
 $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
   return $('<li>').attr("data-context-key", item.value)
      .append(item.label)
      .appendTo(ul);
       var masiive = [] // вот сюда нужно добавить атрибуты которые совпали
   masiive.push(($('li').attr("data-context-key")); //вот так не работает
         alert(masiive)
            };
          }
        });
```

вот полный код : http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/108/

Алгоритм: мы ввели что-то в в инпут есть элементы которые совпали им приписывался атрибут и значение. Теперь получаем доступ ко всем совпавшим элементам li ,берем значение каждого атрибута data context key  и добавляем в массив.

каждый новый поиск данные в массиве обновляются

Comment: А можно какой-то пример? А то я не могу понять что вам надо. Пока вы по коду берете первый из списка и значение аттрибута запихиваете в локальный массив. Даже не так, ваш код вообще не вызывается, потому что идет после return.

Comment: @Vartlok , вот Вы мне прошлый раз , помогли вывести  значение атрибута элемента  li.  (data-context-key : значение атрибута ) по котором окликаешь. А здесь почти тоже самое ток здесь нужно вернуть все совпавшие элементы. И закинуть в массив. Должно получиться чтото типа masive[data-context-key: "шрек",   data-context-key: "шрек2"   ]

Comment: Скрипт выше добавляет атрибут  data-context-key и ему значение , теперь просто нужно получить доступ к этим всем значениям и закидывать их в массив. Ток так , чтоб старые данные удалялись и на их место записывались каждый раз новые данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю вашу проблему то:

```
open: function(event, ui) {
    var scope = this;
    this.masiive = []; // Очищаем массив 
    $("li").click(function() {
        alert($("li[data-context-key]").attr("data-context-key"))
    });
},

create: function() {
    var scope = this;
    scope .masiive = [];
    $(this).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        scope.masiive.push(item.value); // Добавляем значения
        alert(scope.masiive)
        return $('<li>').attr("data-context-key", item.value)
            .append(item.label)
            .appendTo(ul);

    };
}
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает)